# Executing query with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I want to execute a `.sql` script from C#. Basically the script inserts a row into few different tables.

The point is I have values in C# code that I need to pass to the `.sql` query. These values will be collected during program execution.

Here is the query that I want to execute from C# code:

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[User]
           ([Id]
           ,[AccountId]
           ,[FirstName]
           ,[LastName]
           ,[JobTitle]
           ,[PhoneNumber]
          )
     VALUES
           ('00A640BD-1A0D-499D-9155-BA2B626D7B68'
           ,'DCBA241B-2B06-48D7-9AC1-6E277FBB1C2A'
           ,'Mark'
           ,'Wahlberg'
           ,'Actor'
           ,'9889898989'])
GO
```

The values will vary from time to time i.e., they are captured in C# code and need to be passed.

Can anyone please help me do this..I am learning both C# and SQL. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you should try some [**tutorials**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) first, and then ask particular questions here. I find it hard to belive that you didn't get any answer on google.

Comment: sure.. thanks for the link.. newbie on a deadline. hence went for stackoverflow to save my day...

Comment: what, if an actor has name O'Hara ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could open yourself up to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) here, so best practice is to use parameters:

```
using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    dbConn.Open();

    using (SqlTransaction dbTrans = dbConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into [DB].[dbo].[User] ( [Id], [AccountId], [FirstName], [LastName], [JobTitle], [PhoneNumber] ) values ( @id, @accountid, @firstname, @lastname, @jobtitle, @phonenumber );", dbConn))
            {
                dbCommand.Transaction = dbTrans;

                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("id", SqlType.VarChar).Value = id;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("accountid", SqlType.VarChar).Value = accountId;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("firstname", SqlType.VarChar).Value = firstName;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("lastname", SqlType.VarChar).Value = lastName;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("jobtitle", SqlType.VarChar).Value = jobTitle;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("phonenumber", SqlType.VarChar).Value = phoneNumber;

                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            dbTrans.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            dbTrans.Rollback();

            throw; // bubble up the exception and preserve the stack trace
        }
    }

    dbConn.Close();
}
```

This is a good article for [beginners with ADO.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners)

**EDIT** - Just as a bit of extra info, I've added a [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx) to it so if the SQL command fails it will rollback.

Comment: Nice answer. Note you could consider using SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier or GUID for the first two parameters

Comment: @dash yep you certainly could, there's quite a lot to ADO.Net (far more than you can put in a stackoverflow answer) so I've just summarised the basics.

Comment: Ditto! This is how I would do it!

Comment: Actually, I take it back (not the nice answer bit!) - those actually don't seem to be GUID's and hence VarChar is far more appropriate.

Comment: `dbConn.Close();` is not necessary, the connection is closed by the `using` block

Comment: `dbTrans` is not necessary. The insert is atomic already. You only need a transaction if you have more than a single operation. For example read and write, or two writes, etc.

Comment: @dash I know this is a late comment, I just wanna ask something:

Right now is `SqlDbType` the only option to define parameter's type?

Comment: @Simo not sure what your intention is... it's certainly the only option to ensure that the intended type is intrinsic to the database platform you're using.

Answer (score 4):

```
    using SqlCommand cmd= conn.CreateCommand())
    {
                        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMNS) VALUES (@Id, @account etc...


                        cmdUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@User", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = UserTypeID });
                        cmdUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = ApprovalTypeID });
                        cmdUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccountId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = UserID });
                        cmdUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Value = Name });
                        cmdUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Value = Surname });
                        cmdUser.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.Bit) { Value = Active });
    cmdUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_User", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    cn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "00A640BD-1A0D-499D-9155-BA2B626D7B68";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("AccountId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "DCBA241B-2B06-48D7-9AC1-6E277FBB1C2A";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Mark";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Wahlberg";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("JobTitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Actor";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "9889898989";

                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

and for stored procedure, in sql:

```
    create procedure [Insert_User]
(
@id as nvarchar(100),
@accid as nvarchar(100),
@fname as nvarchar(100),
@lname as nvarchar(100),
@jobtitle as nvarchar(100),
@phone as nvarchar(100)
)
    INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[User]
               ([Id]
               ,[AccountId]
               ,[FirstName]
               ,[LastName]
               ,[JobTitle]
               ,[PhoneNumber]
              )
         VALUES
               (@id
               ,@accid
               ,@fname
               ,@lname
               ,@jobtitle
               ,@phone])
```

also, you can use text boxes or other input type controls to set values. You can change dataType, as you wish, such as `uniqueidentifier`, `int`, etc. If one or more of values are set as identifire, eg. AccountID, remove them from query.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, ADO.NET makes it hard to do things like this correctly. Tools like [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) exist to *make that easier*:

```
dbConn.Execute(
     @"insert into [DB].[dbo].[User] ( [Id], [AccountId], [FirstName], [LastName],
                                       [JobTitle], [PhoneNumber] )
       values ( @id, @accountId, @firstName, @lastName, @jobTitle, @phoneNumber )",
       new { id, accountId, firstName, lastName, jobTitle, phoneNumber });
```

This will deal with all the parameterization *for you*, efficiently, effectively, and safely.

There are similar APIs for executing queries and populating objects.

Comment: is that feature useful to prevent invalid data? like escaping some reserved symbols etc

Comment: @anatol can you clarify which "that feature" you are talking about? parameters? yes, absolutely

Comment: excelent! I meant parameters, yeah

Comment: @anatol then: yes

Answer (score 0):

The above answers definitely good solutions for the question. However, I would like to recommend more dynamic and robust solution.

Here is your controller (in my example Ajax call)

```
public JsonResult RecordThis(FormCollection fc)
{
    SqlRecord.RecordThis(fc);
    return View();
}
```

Then, on your Model (in example SqlRecord) create "Record" function;

```
public static void Record(FormCollection fc)
{
   var sql = "INSERT INTO RecordTable VALUES ('@Email','@Name','GETDATE()')";
   var parameters = BuildSqlParams(fc);
   ExecuteInlineSqlWithParams(sql, yourconnectionstringhere, parameters);
}
```

Then, add these two functions below to be used for any function like "Record". You can add conditions as well such as excluding tokens.

```
public static List<SqlParameter> BuildSqlParams(FormCollection fc)
{
     var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
     foreach(var key in fc.AllKeys)
     {   
         if(key != "__RequestVerificationToken")
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@"+key+"", fc[key]));
     }
     return parameters;
}

public static void ExecuteInlineSqlWithParams(string sql, string cnn, List<SqlParameter> parameters )
{
   var connection = new SqlConnection(cnn);
   var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
   command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   foreach(var param in parameters)
   {
      command.Parameters.Add(param);
   }
   using (connection)
   {
      connection.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need the `System.Data.SqlCommand` class.

Change the fixed values to named parameters. For example:

INSERT INTO [TABLE] (Column1) values (@Value1)  // the @Value1 is the named parameter

Example:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "insert...."; // sql command with named parameters

// set the named parameter values
command.Parameters["@Value1"] = "Mark wa...";

// execute 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

SqlCommand reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

Comment: command.Parameters["@Value1"] = "Mark wa..."; gives error: can't convert string to Parameter