# Sql Conversion from nVarchar to int error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select TopicID from Topic where TopicName='Data Structure'' to data type int

Code:

```
public void  BindGridview()
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["infoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    sqlcon.Open();

    string strquery2 = "select TopicID from Topic where TopicName='" + ddltopic.SelectedItem.Text+ "'";

    string strquery3 = "select i.name ,i.score from info as i,Topic as t where  i.topic_id=@topicid";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery3,sqlcon);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topicid",strquery2);

    cmd.Connection = sqlcon;

    SqlDataReader dr;;

    this.GridView1.DataSource =cmd.ExecuteReader();
    this.GridView1.DataBind();

    sqlcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.. Please reply as soon as possible.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the datatype for `TopicID`?

Comment: @user3048066 : If you want to take the TopicID value and to pass to other query stored procedure is good i think.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @user3048066: please tried to create readable query..

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the in the entire query not the topic id in this line here

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topicid",strquery2);
```

It is then taking that as a parameter and adding it to the following query. If this is a subquery, you can always execute it first and then use the result in the paramter.

But the reason that it is failing is because you are essentially trying to compare a `String` to an `int` by passing in the query string like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want in cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topicid",strquery2); is the value returned by strquery2???? , the topic id will get generated if you execute this query first and the result of this will be used instead of query itself

Is that what you want ??

Comment: Thankyou so much Naresh sir for helping..yes that's correct.. you really rock!!! i had been stucked in this problem for three days..So thanku so much for helping..thanks aton!!

Comment: @NareshPansuriya Sir,Now am getting more than one values in my gridview.. and i need only that value coreesponding to it.. for example like student name is: a and b with score 8 and 9.. but they are showing values in gridview more than one.. could you please help...Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: is that question related to current question?

Comment: Yes @naresh sir,, that was related,,but now its working.,so thanku everyone for your quick response and helping me,,thanks aton,,!!

Answer (score 0):

can you tried with below code, I have not tested but its should work for you

```
public void  BindGridview()
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["infoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                sqlcon.Open();
                //Equal is not working when subquery return more records
                string strquery2 = "select i.name ,i.score from info as i,Topic as t where  i.topic_id in (select TopicID from Topic where TopicName=@TopicName)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery2, sqlcon);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopicName", ddltopic.SelectedItem.Text);
                cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
                SqlDataReader dr; ;

                this.GridView1.DataSource =cmd.ExecuteReader();
                this.GridView1.DataBind();
                sqlcon.Close();
}
```

Comment: :The answer was ok. But When we use **in** in SQL query the performance will reduce right.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer, but comments are too short for this.

This code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
string strquery2 = "select TopicID from Topic where TopicName='" + ddltopic.SelectedItem.Text+ "'";
```

Imagine that at some point in the future someone (you or someone else who is modifying your code) decides to replace the drop-down list with a combo box?  Now imagine someone enters this text into the combo box:

```
'; TRUNCATE TABLE Topic; --'
```

Now your SQL server is going to do this:

```
select TopicID from Topic where TopicName = '';
TRUNCATE TABLE Topic; --'
```

[Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425) to use [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905249/920669).