# Faster Way to do Inserts C# & SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am having trouble thinking of a way to do bulk SQL insert commands in C# or even a SQL query.

I usually get a part number list as so... sometimes its 100+ parts

```
LTM-120
LTM-130
LTM-140
LTM-120
LTM-130
LTM-140
```

And, I use a button to insert it in C# as so...

`Textbox20` is the PartNumber and `Textbox15` is the PartNumber ID

```
SqlConnection sqlCon3 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED");
SqlCommand sqlCmd3 = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] " +
                      "([ProductID] ,[Title] ,[ViewOrder]) VALUES ('" +
                      textBox15.Text + "', '" + textBox20.Text + "', NULL) ";
sqlCmd3.Connection = sqlCon3;

sqlCon3.Open();
sqlCmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlCon3.Close();
```

Is there any way to do a bulk query for a bunch of part numbers? Or does anyone have any ideas on how to do something like this?

Comment: Are your partnumber's in an array or list variable?

Comment: Also are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are two different things so please adjust your tags accordingly to get more relevant help.

Comment: SQL Server, and sorry also its just a list in a txt file or excel sheet usually.

Comment: unrelated to the question specifically, but you should probably look at [Parameterized Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters) and not embed the value of the Textboxes directly into your SQL.

Comment: [I really love your code](http://xkcd.com/327/). I wonder what would happen if anybody entered `A'); DROP TABLE Products;--` in your `textBox15`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SqlBulkCopy` to do mass inserts to the DB.

```
    // Create a table with some rows. 
    DataTable newProducts = MakeTable();

    // Create the SqlBulkCopy object.  
    // Note that the column positions in the source DataTable  
    // match the column positions in the destination table so  
    // there is no need to map columns.  
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = 
            "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";

        try
        {
            // Write from the source to the destination.
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newProducts);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Don't I have to stream a txt or xls file?

Comment: @user3014698 No, you can feed it a `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

or you can use parameters its safer

```
SqlConnection sqlCon3 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED");
                SqlCommand sqlCmd3 = new SqlCommand();
                sqlCmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] ([ProductID] ,[Title] ,[ViewOrder]) VALUES (@myID, @myTitle, NULL) ";
                sqlCmd3.Connection = sqlCon3;

                sqlCon3.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    sqlCmd3.Parameters.Add("myID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myobjID[i];
                    sqlCmd3.Parameters.Add("myTitle", SqlDbType.Text).Value = myobjTitle[i];
                    sqlCmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlCmd3.Parameters.Clear();
                }

                sqlCon3.Close();
```

you can also use transactions [Executing query with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905185/executing-query-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You could read into an array and loop through inserting one line at a time. I'm sure there are better solutions than this, but it will work.

Pseudocode-

```
Fill array from file

for(count int = 0; count < arr.length; count++)
{
  sqlcon.open()
  sqlcmd = New select statment with arr[count] values
  sqlcmd.execute
  sqlcon.close()
}
```

Essentially get your data into and array, loop through the array, pull each data value and insert into your DB.  This can cause issues if you have bad data.  You may want to do some research on SQL Injection and Parameters to implement some methods to ensure you DB doesn't get corrupted.

EDIT:

While safer with a close connection each time how much will this effect speed? I would assume opening and closing the connection every time would be slower than open before the loop and close after data processing is done.

EDIT 2:

Do as stated above, but instead of filling from a static file fill the array from the user selected file by implementing a browse/open file capability seen here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415(v=vs.95).aspx

Then your `INSERT` statement will remain constant for each value except for the new data value being inserted.

Comment: I'd recommend you use the `using` statement at best. At least, close the connection before exiting the loop.

Comment: @FrazellThomas Yes, I agree. Much can be done to the Pseudocode to make it better in terms of efficiency, reliability, and integrity, but I wanted to give OP a direction to go. It's been a bit since C# as well so my function calls and syntax are a bit rusty hence the Pseudocode and not a working code solution.

Comment: No problem. I was just making an edit recommendation, but text makes it sound a lot less nice than I intended it to. Additionally, .NET uses connection pooling so rapidly opening and closing connections is faster than exhausting the connection pool.

Comment: What I would like to do is read from a txt file of the parts in a list and insert a query for all of those partnumbers specifically

Comment: @user3014698 Can you be a little clearer on what you want. I'm not sure I know what your saying. Do you want to insert everything at once like the solution FrazellThomas provided or one at a time like the solution I provided? Also do you want to read straight from a file straight into your DB instead of filling an array?

Comment: @shadowjfaith sorry, thanks for your help what I really want is to click a button and then you select a txt file on your computer or have it read from a specific place on the computer and executes the same query for each of the partnumbers in the txt file.

Comment: @user3014698 Refer to my second edit. To do this effectively without things breaking, you will have to 1) Prevent SQL Injection by checking the data in the array before the sqlcmd and 2) Ensuring that the file is in fact something that can fill an array in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different techniques for doing multiple INSERTs at once.  Other answers have discussed these (SqlBulkCopy, BULK INSERT, etc.)

You can also build a SQL statement that does multiple INSERTs at once.  For example, using `INSERT VALUES`, string multiple VALUES clauses together:

```
INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] ([ProductID], [Title], [ViewOrder])
VALUES (1, 'Title 1', NULL),
    (2, 'Title 2', NULL),
    -- etc.
```

Or use INSERT with a UNION:

```
INSERT INTO [Products].[Features] ([ProductID], [Title], [ViewOrder])
SELECT 1, 'Title 1', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Title 2', NULL
UNION ALL -- etc.
```

You really need to be careful with your parameters, however.  As others have pointed out, your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Copy is certainly a way to go.

However, since your data set is relative small (100 items), you might consider using SQL Server's support for XML. Given a table like this:

```sql
create table dbo.item
(
  id    int          not null primary key clustered ,
  name  varchar(100) not null unique nonclustered ,
)
```

You can write a stored procedure like this:

```sql
create procedure dbo.insert_items

  @item_list xml

as

  insert dbo.item
  (
    id   ,
    name
  )
  select id   =              X.value( './id[1]'   , 'int'          )    ,
         name = ltrim(rtrim( X.value( './name[1]' , 'varchar(100)' ) ))
  from @item_list.nodes('/items/item') as itemList(X) 

  return @@rowcount
go
```

which can be invoked like this (in SQL Server Management Studio):

```sql
exec insert_items '
  <items>
    <item><id> 1 </id><name> alpha   </name></item>
    <item><id> 2 </id><name> bravo   </name></item>
    <item><id> 3 </id><name> charlie </name></item>
    <item><id> 4 </id><name> delta   </name></item>
  </items>
  '
```

Or, from C#, like this:

```cs
string connect_string = "Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;" ;

string myXmlString    = @"
  <items>
    <item><id> 1 </id><name> alpha   </name></item>
    <item><id> 2 </id><name> bravo   </name></item>
    <item><id> 3 </id><name> charlie </name></item>
    <item><id> 4 </id><name> delta   </name></item>
  </items>
" ;

using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect_string) )
using ( SqlCommand    cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
{
  cmd.CommandText = "dbo.insert_items" ;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@item_list" , myXmlString ) ;
  conn.Open() ;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ;
  conn.Close() ;
}
```

Then it's a taking your part number list and serializing it into suitable XML (if it's not already) and building the correct XQuery/XPath in your stored procedure to pull out the necessary bits.

In the real world, since XML processing can be...expensive and painful, I find it easiest to have the stored procedure first load the XML into a temporary table using OpenXml() first, just to get dealing with the XML out of the way up front. That done, the remainder of the stored procedure can be straight SQL. It simplifies debugging and maintenance, too.