# Adding an IF statement

Tags: c#, winforms, button, if-statement

I wanted to add an if statement to this code that says..

IF i click this button , it will check if the ListU.SelectedValue is empty or not , and if it is empty , a messagebox saying "please pick a name before continuing" , and if it is not empty , the code then runs.

how do i do that?

this is the code for the button click. (i know , my code needs some parameter , we can ignore that for the moment)

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //update code//
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
   conn.Open();

   SqlDataAdapter daCount = new SqlDataAdapter("select iCount from ComDet where cName = @cName", conn);
   daCount.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ListU.SelectedValue;

   DataTable dtC = new DataTable();
   daCount.Fill(dtC);
   DataRow firstRow = dtC.Rows[0];

   string x = firstRow["iCount"].ToString();
   int y = Int32.Parse(x);
   int z = y + 1;

   SqlCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set iCount = " + z + ", ViewTime = '" + lblTime.Text + "', LastView = '" + txtUser2.Text + "' Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

    cmdC.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    var ufdet = new UserFullDetail(ListU.SelectedValue.ToString());
    ufdet.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: What kind of control is ListU? a drop down list? something else?

Comment: well , a combobox is a dropdownlist , isnt?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, bu you MUST learn about [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and use [request parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905185/executing-query-with-parameters) (you seems to use it in the select, why not using parameters in you update ?)

Comment: @Olivier - that's why i put in the description that i know my code needs some parameters.. :) im going to update all my codes to that method in a sec.. :)

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin Right, I didnt see that part :)

Comment: @Olivier - no probs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(ListU.SelectedValue == null || ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() == string.Empty)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Select something from the listbox, please");      
   }
else
   {
   //update code//
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
   conn.Open();

   SqlDataAdapter daCount = new SqlDataAdapter("select iCount from ComDet where cName = @cName", conn);
   daCount.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ListU.SelectedValue;

   DataTable dtC = new DataTable();
   daCount.Fill(dtC);
   DataRow firstRow = dtC.Rows[0];

   string x = firstRow["iCount"].ToString();
   int y = Int32.Parse(x);
   int z = y + 1;

   SqlCommand cmdC = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmdC.CommandText = "Update ComDet set iCount = " + z + ", ViewTime = '" + lblTime.Text + "', LastView = '" + txtUser2.Text + "' Where cName = '" + ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

    cmdC.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    var ufdet = new UserFullDetail(ListU.SelectedValue.ToString());
    ufdet.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your return statement is redundant, and else is misspelt.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(ListU.SelectedValue == null || ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() == string.Empty)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Select something from the listbox, please");
       return;
   }
   .....
```

Comment: Not really necessary. If the IF is true then you exit the method, so there is no need to add an else for the rest of your code

Comment: By the way, it is debatable if it is correct to return in this way without add an else statement. In theory every method should have just one return point but for simple cases like these I find that following the theory is just a pain....

Comment: @Steve That theory is outdated and debated.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListU.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please pick a name before continuing.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Run the code.
    }
}
```

This makes the else condition explicit, rather than implied as in Steve's example.

Another approach would be to only enable button4 if something is selected in ListU, e.g.,

```
private void ListU_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    button4.Enabled = ListU.SelectedItem != null;
}
```

Comment: You need to hook the method into the correct event. See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dacysss4(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(ListU.SelectedValue == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(ListU.SelectedValue)))
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Select something from the listbox.");
    return;
  }
.....
```