# Can I execute SQL with parameters from within Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

**EDIT**: Judging from the comments, I have been unclear in what I am trying to achieve. I'll try from another angle.

I have been developing sprocs for a number of years. I increasingly feel that choosing between SQL embedded in C# code and sprocs are both bad choices. I know that many people will disagree and that's fine.
I didn't elaborate on this in the question to avoid having the discussion be about sprocs or not :-) .

As an experiment, I have tried embedding `.sql` files in my project in Visual Studio. Literally, in my project tree I have files with the `.sql` extension and the `Build Action` set to `Embedded Resource`.

That way I can edit the SQL query code from within VS and even run/execute it from within VS, without running the project. I love that. The actual code that I am working on right now, is akin to a "product list" with paging and multiple ordering and filtering options. The SQL query has parameters like `@skip`, `@search`, etc. This means that if I try to run/execute it from within VS (specifically by pressing `CTRL + SHIFT + e` or selecting "Execute" from the "SQL" menu in VS) these parameters are missing (of course), since they are meant to be provided as `SqlParameter` at runtime. I understand *why* this happens and by no way intend to imply that either VS or SSMS is bugged. I am merely looking for a way to "tell" VS that "When I execute this query from within VS, I intend for `@skip` to be `10`". I (perhaps mistakenly) assumed that the reason that VS had IntelliSense support and Execute support for `.sql` files was to support a scenario akin to what I am trying).

I was just hoping someone else was doing the same and had a clever way/addon/trick to support it.

**EDIT END**

In an project in Visual Studio 2017, I have a number of .sql files which are embedded into the application when built.
While editing the files in VS, I can conveniently connect to a SQL server and execute the query.
However, if the query has parameters like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ID=@ID;
```

The execution, from within Visual Studio, fails with

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
```

This can be "fixed" by adding a line at the top of the script/file, so it looks like:

```
DECLARE @ID int = 123;
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ID=@ID;
```

However, now it doesn't work when called from within the code like this (using Dapper, it's not relevant to the question, but explains the syntax):

```
var emp = conn.Query<Employee>( sql, new { ID=123 } );
```

I was hoping that either I could specify the value of ID somewhere not in the file, or specify some part of the file which VS would execute, but would be ignored later when calling from code.

EDIT: To be clear, I can craft the SQL so that it works flawlessly from within Visual Studio *or* at runtime, but I cannot have both. I was hoping there was some neat hack, a VS addon or just some VS feature that I was just missing. I have considered adding a simple pre-processor so I can do something like this:

```
--if DEBUG
DECLARE @ID int = 123;
--endif
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ID=@ID;
```

And then I could add it to my function that loads the embedded resource.

Comment: Can't you store the SQL on the server as Stored Procedures?

Comment: I could but would rather avoid it. We have yet to find a satisfying solution to DB version control, so I would rather not store code in the DB.
Besides, how would that help me edit and execute it from within VS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing query with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905185/executing-query-with-parameters)

Comment: @AlexK. stored procedures are an unrelated discussion; sometimes valid, sometimes not - but simply: unrelated: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html (see: Part The Second)

Comment: "However, now it doesn't work when called from within the code like this" - what *happens*?  is `sql` the value that you expect it to be? what you show *should work fine* as long as `sql` is the string like the one in your question. Dapper doesn't care where the string *comes from*. It only cares what the string *contains* - so: what is the value of `sql` ?

Comment: @PeterB I don't think it is a useful duplicate, to be honest; whatever happening: is happening separately to this

Comment: @PeterB - My question is about executing the same SQL from within VS and at runtime

Comment: @Marc Gravel I have edited the question to make my intention more clear. If add the DECLARE line to `sql` then I get an SqlException that `The variable name '@ID' has already been declared`, but if I omit it then I cannot execute it from VS because `Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".` Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @ThomasM.H. not really - what script is this, how was it created and how is it used? Scripts like those generated by SSMS, the pre/post-deployment scripts of database projects are meant to be executed with sqlcmd or SSMS, and use [scripting variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables) to set parameter values, eg with `:SETVAR`. Queries meant to be executed by clients don't understand scripting variables or batch commands like `GO`. How did you end up with a file without scripting variables or variable declarations?

Comment: @ThomasM.H. are you talking about *content files* that you use to store SQL strings and just happen to have the `.sql` extension? Visual Studio will treat them like SQL scripts. It doesn't see any parameters, it sees undeclared T-SQL variables. There are no parameters in a SQL script, only scripting variables that *may* get their data from the command line

Comment: @Panagiotis Ok, I'll try again. The script is handcrafted by me. The actual SQL code is longer, but I tried to condense it for the question. What I want to achieve is to craft a parameterized query, which works at runtime **and** from within VS, without modification. Maybe it's not possible, but one can hope :-) It's basically just me being lazy and wanting to optimize my workflow. Currently I'm copy-pasting SQL code back and forth between VS and SSMS and it just seems needlessly prone to errors.

Comment: @ThomasM.H. you are trying to make VS guess what you want to do - that's the only way it could change the behavior of T-SQL variables to script variables and vice-versa. It's similar to asking C# to treat something undeclared as a variable or parameter. Either you have a SQL script or you don't. If you want to optimize your workflow create stored procedures and views. Create a database project to hold and version them. Use schema compare to detect and apply changes. You can reverse-engineer an existing database into a database project. It's not SSMS or VS that are error prone.

Comment: @Panagiotis I would say that I'm trying to tell VS what I want to do :-) Maybe the problem is that I'm using the .sql extension wrong. And maybe you are right that I should just use stored procedures. We already have a procedure for change scripts, so that's not the problem. It's rather that I really dislike editing and using stored procedures. If my question or comments indicated that I think VS or SSMS are error prone, I apologize - that was never my intention.

Comment: You could probably create a powershell script that could take a .sql projetc file, parse it for parameters, and then prompt you to enter values (or grab values from another file) for each one.

Comment: Ah, a kindred spirit. Have you found a suitable solution, DenverCoder9?

Answer (score 1):

Pardon if I understood the question wrongly. Could it be you're looking for something like this? The query approach actually doesn't matter, it more looks like the issue is that you declare it like @ID when you actually have to add the replacement to the script itself

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ID=@ID;";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", actualID); <--this is is why declaring doesn't work - You can declare it, but you also need to add it to the query
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Note: everything here is already what Dapper (the code shown in the question) would already have done. So while there's nothing *wrong* with the code in this answer - it also doesn't change anything from what is in the question

Comment: My point is, the SQL in your example is not executable from within VS or SSMS, it will complain that @ID is undeclared.
In my actual code, `CommandText` is maybe 50 lines long and resides in a file with the `.sql` extension. I can handily execute this file against Sql Server from within VS via the `SQL -> Execute` menu, but only if there are no undeclared parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Five years have passed since the original post remains without the answer, and now I stumbled upon it because I am trying to do exactly the same as Thomas.
One way to do it, which is far from perfect, is to add the parameters with test values in the SQL file on top of the query. (e.g. DECLARE @p1=10) Later they need to be removed of course.
What is needed in my view in VS is a user interface like when a stored procedure with parameters is run from SQL Server Management studio and it pops up with a form where parameters can be set before the SP runs.