# How to use Column Names from list into MySql insert

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, sqlparameter

I have 2 lists:

```
List<string> ColumnNames = new List<string>();
List<string> ValueNames = new List<string>();
ColumnNames = names.Keys.ToList();
ValueNames = names.Values.ToList();
```

I'm trying to use this lists into MySql statement:

```
...
MySqlCommand command = conDataBase.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = string.Format("insert into MyTable {0} values (?parameter)", string.Join(",", ColumnNames));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", string.Join(",", ValueNames));
...
```

Here I take error in syntax

```
...
command.CommandText = "insert into MyTable (" + string.Join(",", ColumnNames) + ") values ('" + string.Join(",", ValueNames) + "')";
...
```

and

```
...
command.CommandText = "insert into MyTable (" + string.Join(",", ColumnNames) + ") values (?parameter)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", string.Join(",", ValueNames));
...
```

In last 2 Codes I'm taking error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, but

```
ColumnNames.Count = ValueNames.Count
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing query with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905185/executing-query-with-parameters)

Comment: You need to add all parameter names and each parameter-mapping on its own. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905249/7505395 on how it should look.   Variablenames in your command-text should be prefixed by `@` - you use the same name when adding the parameter with the value to the query.

Comment: I tryed this too and I have same error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I think there is a problem in variable ColumnNames, not in Values, and the list.count will be different in different gridviews, so the sample you give me not answering the problem ((

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1225444/How-to-use-column-names-from-list-into-mysql-inser

```
List<string> ColumnNames = names.Keys.ToList()
List<string> ValueNames = names.Values.ToList();
List<string> RevValueNames = new List<string>();
ValueNames.ForEach(x => RevValueNames.Add("'" + x + "'"));
string Query = string.Format("insert into MyTable ({0}) values ({1})", string.Join(",", ColumnNames), string.Join(",", RevValueNames));
                command.CommandText = Query;
```

Comment: You should _never_ use user-input strings and string-concatenate them into your sql. Google Sql injection.  Or think about what happens if I input this into one of your Textboxes:  `'); TRUNCATE MyTable; DROP TABLE MyTable;` Using `SqlParameter`  prevents this.

Comment: but I have  no choice, I have many tables and many gridviews and I wont to write 1 module fro all of them, and column names and quantity are different

Answer (score 0):

This is, what you could "script" using the answer provided in the other question:

```
string tableName = "Person";

// the names of the columns in your table    
var columnNames = new List<string> { "Name", "Age", "BirthDate" };

// the data you want to store in each column
var data = new List<string> { "Klaus", "22", "Before 2010" };

var myColumns = string.Join (", ", columnNames.Select (n => string.Format("[{0}]",n)));
var myParamColumns = string.Join (", ", columnNames.Select (n => string.Format("@{0}",n)));

using (var dbCommand = new SqlCommand() /*conDataBase.CreateCommand ()*/)
{ 
    dbCommand.CommandText = string.Format ("insert into {0}  ( {1} ) values ( {2} );", tableName, myColumns, myParamColumns);

    // your insert now looks like this:
    // insert into Person  ( [Name], [Age], [BirthDate] ) values ( @Name, @Age, @BirthDate );

    Console.WriteLine (dbCommand.CommandText);

    // then you add each single piece of data to each used @....    

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
      dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue (columnNames[i], data[i]);

    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it's better to use:
List<string> RevValueNames = new List<string>();
myParamColumns.ForEach(x => RevValueNames.Add("'" + x + "'"));