# Data type mismatch using execute scalar

Tags: c#, ms-access, executescalar

I'm looking to fetch sum of ALLOCATED_DEPOSIT from Allocations using Invoice_No. I'm getting all the details through datareader but **only execute scalar is being a problem for me**. I tried everything but using the following code it gives **"data type mismatch error"** always.

```
connection.Close();

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string cstrQuery = "SELECT SUM (ALLOCATED_DEPOSIT)FROM ALLOCATIONS WHERE INVOICE_NO= " + int.Parse(txt_Invoiceno.Text);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cstrQuery, connection);
            int sum = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            //long sum = (long)dt.Compute("Sum(ALLOCATED_DEPOSIT)", "True");

            textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you are getting? Which line in the code throws the error?

Comment: If Invoice_No is text type, use apostrophe delimiters for the parameter. Or instead of parameter concatenation, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905185/executing-query-with-parameters

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the `ExecuteScalar()` can return `null`.

You are also using the result as a `string` so no need to convert to `int` then to `string`.

Do this instead:

```
var sumObject = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(sumObject != null)
{
    textBox1.Text = sumObject.ToString();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong!");
}
```

Inferring from you query I would guess the values in the field `ALLOCATED_DEPOSIT` are floating point and not integer, thus the sum of which would be floating point. That might be the "data type mismatch error" you are seeing.

Comment: I figured it out that Invoice_no had to be "int" in DB and ALLOCATED_DEPOSIT had to be "text". It works now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you feel like this answer helped, please feel free to "accept" the answer.